# How to retrieve nested data from Firebase using StreamBuilder and display it all to ListView?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to create a leaderboard that shows all user's children that has answered the quiz. I don't have any idea to achieve this.

This is my database : -

[image]

This is how I want to display it : -

[image]

I'm stuck and really need help.

I've tried searching and this is my code at the moment,

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(currentUser!.uid)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      var data = snapshot.data.data();
                      var anak = data['anak'];

                      return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: anak.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Text(anak[index].toString());
                          });
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("Something went wrong");
                    }

                    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                      return Text("Document does not exist");
                    } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator(color: lightBlue);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

But I have an error, "The getter 'length' was called on null"